# Parameter type less accessible than method in a singleton implementation

Tags: c#, singleton, encapsulation

I'm writing an application in C# for which I need a singleton object; so there'll only be one object of that class. But that class needs to have a list of references to objects of another class of the system, so I added such a list as an attribute and then created a method to add another object to it.

I thought it to be correct but I'm getting an error where a parameter type (the class to be in the list) is less accessible than a method (`AddNew` in the following code).

Here is what I have so far:

```
namespace One {
   public sealed class Singleton {
      // Only instance of the class:
      private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton ();
      private List<MyOtherClass> list;

      static Singleton() { }
      private Singleton() {
         list = new List<MyOtherClass>();
      }

      // Accessor to the property (the instance per se):
      public static Singleton Instance {
         get {
            return instance;
         }
      }

      // Method to add a new object to the list:
      public void AddNew(MyOtherClass newObject) {
         list.Add(newObject);
      }
   }
}
```

The class whose objects are to be inside that list is defined as follows:

```
namespace One {
   class MyOtherClass {
      ... // With private attributes and public constructor and methods.
   }
}
```

Where could the problem be? Is it not possible to accomplish what I wanted? The class is public and resides in the same namespace where the singleton class is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where could the problem be?

Exactly what the compiler says. `MyOtherClass` is an *internal* class (implicitly), but you've included it as a parameter to a *public* method in a *public* class, which you can't do.

Options:

- Make `Singleton` internal
- Make `AddNew` internal
- Make `MyOtherClass` public

Note that namespaces are entirely separate to access modifiers - they're irrelevant here.

Comment: I see so the default protection level of a class is `internal`, I thought they'd be public if I didn't specify otherwise. Actually until I read these answers I never heard of the `internal` level, I need to do some serious reading on C# if I'm to learn and use it right. Thanks you for the answer, I think I'll make the singleton class internal then.

Comment: @JamesRussell: All you need to remember is that in general, if you don't specify any access modifier, C# will default to the most private it could be specified as.

Answer (score 2):

Your `MyOtherClass` is `internal`, but your `Singleton.AddNew` method is public.

A top-level class is internal by default if you don't specify a protection modifier.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I thought the default level to be public if not specified; never heard of `internal` before I read both your answers.

Comment: Note that nested types are `private` by default rather than `internal`.